# The app with same bundle id but from different projects wouldn't update

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Some background of the issue:

1. I have a Xcode project named **A**. It has a bundle ID **com.abc.tung**. It was on AppStore already and had few app version updates with no issues.
2. Later we decided to re-write the app and create a new project in Xcode named **B**. We also gave it the same bundle ID **com.abc.tung**. We uploaded a new build to AppStore Connect, everything was fine, it went to correct app in the AppStore Connect. Then we released it to AppStore.

The problem:

Some of the users reported an issue that even after the update to the newest version (the version that came from project **B**), it would still open them an old app with old functionality.

Please help me to understand how is it possible? Or even if you had similar issues, please also comment since it might also be some issues with AppStore?

Comment: Some sort of caching?

Comment: They haven't actually updated the app on their device?  Just because the update is on the App Store, it doesn't mean that *they have updated*

Comment: Wait. few hours for until new version available on the app store and make sure they are updated and check the "App store" app updated Tab.

Comment: @Paulw11 they did .. the proof was that in AppStore app they had a button “open” instead of “update”. And also they did update because I saw how they did it.

Comment: @NazmulHasan the issue was reproduced few days after the update was on AppStore.

Comment: What technology does your app use?  If it is native code (Swift/Objective C) then I can't understand how this can happen if they have updated.  If you are using some sort of hybrid app technology then maybe there was an issue with caching or something.

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah, pure Swift. I also can't get it ..

Answer (score 0):

Since bundle ID hasn't changed, it might be a build version question.

Need to find out what app build version was submitted to AppStore as B, and what build version was installed on the device.

The version on iOS is the release version (like 1.2.3) + a build number (can be just a single number like 4), so the full build version looks like 1.2.3(4).

It is a good idea to display the full version inside the app UI to make it easier for the end users to report it to you.

Comment: Thanks! Good idea. I'll try to reproduce it. The version was 1.4 and now it's 2.1. Agree!